# Having confusion while inorderly traversing through a Binary Search Tree

Tags: ruby

just having a bit of confusion while recursively traversing through BST,  the type of traversal is inorder. here is the code.  if a block is given the method yields the node to the block. Right now i am lost with the arrays. Whats confusing is, When its done going to the leftmost node. its gonna add it to the array and lets say that the leftmost node does not have a right child, when the leftmost node returns control to the parent node/method, the leftmost nodes value is still present in the array while i never returned the array to the parent. This obviously only happens with a node that does not have a child because of the return statement i put at the end of the method 'return if node.right_node == nil && node.left_node == nil' which causes the present frame to return so it shouldnt return the modified array right, but when the control is returned the array is modified and infact has the added element.

```
def inorder(node=root,array=Array.new)
   inorder(node.left_node,array) if has_left(node)

    if block_given?
      yield(node.value)
    else
      array << node.value
    end

    inorder(node.right_node,array) if has_right(node)
    return if node.right_node == nil && node.left_node == nil
    return array if !block_given?
  end
```

Comment: What is a “BST”? (I assume it’s not a variant of a [BLT](https://www.google.com/search?q=blt&rlz=1C9BKJA_enCA849CA849&hl=en-US&prmd=imnv&sxsrf=ALeKk011VVQiTLma0E50GJ5UdP64NJ-BVw:1589735584891&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9uMvGsrvpAhXPIDQIHTo8DxYQ_AUoAXoECBUQAQ&biw=1112&bih=725&dpr=2#imgrc=9LOR0g6Kc3MZmM).)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Binary Search Tree. Kind of the same thing as a BLT but with less bacon.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Haha, its a binary search tree.